# how to build WCF service suitable for java client

Tags: java, .net, wcf, binding

i have developed a WCF service with basichttpbinding.The client using my WCF service is a Java app.

1. My java app client often face connection time out when sending data for operation taking more than 10 minutes.if sending data for less operation then the it works fine. What can i do to fix this?
2. When the java client throws connection time out issue.despite the connection timeout in java client , my WCF service is processing the operation it was initially invoked by java client. Why is my wcf service still doing the operation , when my java client has already thrown connection time out?
3. What type of binding can i use for java client to interact with my WCF service?

Answer (score 0):

> my java app client often face connection time out when sending data
>   for operation taking more than 10 minutes.if sending data for less
>   operation then the it works fine.what can i do to fix this.

Connection timeout is a client side thing. You client is saying "this is taking too long for the service to respond" and throwing an exception. The server doesn't care how long the call takes and will continue to process the call beyond your client's timeout threshold.

> why is my wcf service still doing the operation , when my java client
>   has already thrown connection time out?

Answered above, but it's because the service doesn't care (not should it), that the client has thrown out and aborted the call. It's not like a SQL database connection where the client closing the connection will abort the operation.

> what type of binding can i use for java client to interact with my WCF
>   service?

The only type of binding supporting Java clients is the one you are already using. I would try to increase the equivalent of the [Send Timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.sendtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx) on your Java client if there is one.

The alternative would be to decrease the amount of time calls are taking to return, perhaps by taking the service-side processing offline by using something like [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) or another backgrounder.